# Solving a recurrence relation using Z transform

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence using Z transforms:

For $n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$

$T(n)=1\ for\ n< 4$

$T(n)=T(\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \rfloor)+T(\lfloor \frac{3n}{4} \rfloor)+n\ for\ n\geq 4$

I should find an expression for T(n).

Using $Z[T(n)](z)$ as the Z transform for T(n) (or more simply, just $Z[T(n)]$), I have arrived to the following solution attempt:

$Z[T(n)]=Z[T(\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \rfloor)]+Z[T(\lfloor \frac{3n}{4} \rfloor)]+\frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$

Using the property of linearity of any Z transformation we can add the arguments of the first two terms of the right side and get the following:

$Z[T(n)]=Z[T(\frac{n}{4})+T(\frac{3n}{4})]+\frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$

or

$Z[T(n)]=Z[T(n)-n]+\frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$

I guess that the first term of the right side of the equation is just $Z[T(n)]$ shifted to the right with n units, and so it can be written as follows:

$Z[T(n)-n]=\frac{Z[T(n)]}{z^{n}}$

Therefore, the equation becomes

$Z[T(n)]=\frac{Z[T(n)]}{z^{n}}+\frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$

By subtracting from both sides of the equation the first term of the right side we get:

$Z[T(n)]\cdot \frac{z^{n}-1}{z^{n}}=\frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$

and therefore

$Z[T(n)]=\frac{z^{n+1}}{(z-1)^{2}\cdot (z^{n}-1)}$

Now the problem is that it is very difficult for me to reverse transform this (I don't even know how to find a value for the convergence radius). I have a strong feeling that I was wrong somewhere along the way, so I would like to know if there is a better way to do this using Z transforms.

And if there is not the case, can anybody please explain to me if Z transforms can be used at all to solve this equation?

And if not, can anybody please tell me if there is a way to calculate an upper bound for T(n) (which is reasonably low)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of the $Z$ transform above is not correct.  For example, the equation
$$
Z[T(n)-n]=\frac{Z[T(n)]}{z^{n}}
$$
is not correct.  Instead, you have
$$
Z[T(n)-n] = Z[T(n)] - Z[n] = Z[T(n)] - \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}
$$
which, when substituted into
$$Z[T(n)]=Z[T(n)-n]+\frac{z}{(z-1)^{2}}$$
results in the trivial
$$
Z[T(n)]=Z[T(n)].
$$
To obtain a nontrivial equation for $Z[T(n)]$, you have to first express the $Z$ transforms of $T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor)$ and $T(\lfloor 3n/4 \rfloor)$ in terms of the $Z$ transform of $T(n)$ (taking $T(n)$ here to be an arbitrary sequence), and then use the recurrence to express $Z[T(n)]$ in terms of the $Z$ transforms of $T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor)$ and $T(\lfloor 3n/4 \rfloor)$, also taking into account the initial values $T(1)=T(2)=T(3)=1$.  Although it is possible to do this, the expressions that result are rather complex, so it would be difficult to solve this problem directly using the $Z$ transform.

Using a result of S. Roura (["An improved master theorem for divide-and-conquer recurrences", S. Roura, 1997](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-63165-8_201)) it is possible to show that
$$
T(n)\sim C_0 n \ln n, \qquad \text{where } C_0=-(\frac 14 \ln \frac 14+\frac 34 \ln \frac 34)^{-1} \approx 1.77829895.
$$
Also, a generalized form of the recurrence for $T(n)$ is analyzed by Drmota and Szpankowski in ["A master theorem for discrete divide and conquer recurrences", 2011.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2133064)  Their Theorem 2.1 also shows in this case that $T(n)\sim Cn\ln n$ for some constant $C$.

For $C_0$ as above, it is straightforward to show by induction that $T(n)\le C_0 n\ln n$ for all $n\ge 2$.  This can be checked directly for $2\le n\le 7$.  Then, if $n\ge8$, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(n)&=&T(\lfloor \frac n4 \rfloor)+T(\lfloor \frac{3n}4\rfloor)+n\\
&\le& 
C_0 (\lfloor \frac n4 \rfloor \ln \lfloor \frac {n}4 \rfloor)+
C_0 (\lfloor \frac{3n}4 \rfloor \ln \lfloor \frac {3n}4 \rfloor)+
n,\\
&\ & \qquad \qquad \text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
&\le& C_0 (\frac n4  \ln  \frac {n}4 )+C_0(\frac {3n}4 \ln \frac{3n}4) + n\\
&=& C_0 (\frac n4 \ln n + \frac {3n}4 \ln n + \frac n4 \ln \frac 14 +  \frac {3n}4 \ln \frac 34) + n\\
&=& C_0 n \ln n + C_0 ( \frac 14 \ln \frac 14 +  \frac {3}4 \ln \frac 34)n + n\\
&=& C_0 n \ln n,
\end{eqnarray*}
completing the induction.

Comment: When I was thought the Z transform they told me I could use it to solve any constant coefficient recurrence and I wanted to get its money's worth. Thanks for the useful answer. That induction provided a nice approach.